# Setting up a route that includes more than 1 resource id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 resources - Institute and Classroom. There is a has_many association between Institute and Classroom.

Please let me know how I can setup the following route for the "show" action in the Classrooms Controller:

```
institutes/<institute_id>/classrooms/<classroom_id>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
resources :institutes do
  resources :classrooms
end
```

You might find it beneficial to look at the documentation on routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)